# What is the equivalent in ECS fields reference of Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nlog, elastic-common-schema

I'm working with a .NET framework application and for the logs i use NLog logging them on a ElasticSearch target using an ECS(Elastic Common Schema) layout.
example:
[image]

One of the parameters i'm logging is the activityId:
[image]

It is well explained on [this](https://lowleveldesign.org/2012/05/27/grouping-application-traces-using-activityid/) article.

Since i'm using an Nlog log layout, that tries to implement [ECS 1.5](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/1.5/ecs-source.html) i'm wondering if anyone knows to which property activityId corresponds to? I think that `event.id` may make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think `event.id` is more like a Windows EventLog-EventId, that remains static independent of context. Where ActivityId is unique for each request.

Not sure where you have found NLog Layout of `xsi:type="ElasticSearch"`. But when looking at EcsLayout here:

https://github.com/elastic/ecs-dotnet/tree/master/src/Elastic.CommonSchema.NLog

Then the these values are mapped:

- Transaction.Id = Identifier for the entire transaction. Ex. `${ElasticApmTransactionId}`
- Trace.Id = CorrelationId for the current request. Ex. `${ElasticApmTraceId}`
- Span.Id = ActivityId for an operation within a request.

See also: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/current/ecs-tracing.html

I guess the field to choose depends on what value you have decided to store in `Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId`.

In the "new" world, then Microsoft is now selling [System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.activity.current). See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.DiagnosticSource